# No Ciphers Available Error (MySQL Connector Python)

Tags: python, mysql

I tried to connect to MYSQL database for a project but I always run into this error.

```
myobj = mysql.connector.connect(host = "localhost", user = "root", passwd = "root", database = "db")
c = myobj.cursor()
if myobj.is_connected():
    print("connected")
else:
    print("not connected")
```

And this is the error that I receive:

```
mysql.connector.errors.InterfaceError: 2055: Lost connection to MySQL server at 'localhost:3306', system error: 1 [SSL: NO_CIPHERS_AVAILABLE] no ciphers available (_ssl.c:992)
```

Thank you

Comment: mysql forces a ssl connection, that is on local connection not necessary

Comment: so is there a way to fix this?

Comment: check the my.cnf/ini file where the ssl is enabled https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/using-encrypted-connections.html

Comment: okay i checked the my.ini file and disabled ssl (if that was the right thing to do) but i am still running into the same error

Comment: then there is still some ssl remaining,